# suma dependiendo de una condición

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

```
tabla codigos

códigos  | valores |  valida              
---------------------------------- 
1        |   10    |   SI
---------------------------------- 
1        |   20    |   SI
----------------------------------
2        |   10    |   SI
----------------------------------
2        |   40    |   SI
```

tabla de código

```
códigos  | acumulado             
----------------- 
1        |   0
----------------- 
2        |   0
-----------------
```

tengo la duda de si es posible sumar los valores por código de la primera tabla, y luego actualizar estos valores en la segunda tabla dependiendo del código

ejemplo de como debería quedar

```
códigos  | acumulado             
----------------- 
1        |   30
----------------- 
2        |   50
-----------------
```

y así queda la otra tabla

```
códigos  | valores |  valida              
---------------------------------- 
1        |   10    |   NO
---------------------------------- 
1        |   20    |   NO
----------------------------------
2        |   10    |   NO
----------------------------------
2        |   40    |   NO
```

Comment: si que se puede.. que intentaste?

Comment: pude sumar los valores con SELECT distinct codigos,sum (valores)
from tabla1 GROUP BY codigos. en la primera tabla pero no se como actualizar estos datos en la segunda ósea podría almacenar este valor en una tabla temporal luego insertarlo en la segunda pero no lo veo bien , también pensaba usar un case pero nunca eh trabajado con case en sql

Comment: Y hacer un insert into de esa consulta?

Comment: exacto aria un insert into de la columna luego de a ver sumado en mi tabla temporal a eso te refieres?

Comment: no... hacer un insert into directamente de esa consulta.. no necesitas la temporal

Comment: creo que lo veo pero a la vez no, voy a probar

Comment: creo que no me sirve por que la idea es hacer un update a la otra tabla y no insertar datos como tal ya que esa data ya contiene datos, seria como el código 1 acumula esa cantidad o no lo veo

Comment: se puede hacer tambien directo en el update, ahora te escribo una respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si queres ir guardando los valores de tu otra consulta sin tener que usar una tabla temporal, simplemente hace un update que use el resultado de un select particular como valor.

Podes hacer algo asi:

```
Update codigo 
set acumulado = 
    (select sum(valores) from codigos where codigo.acumulado = codigos.acumulado)
```

Igual, es raro que quieras guardar un valor acumulado (salvo que sea un datawarehouse).. si el valor puede cambiar en el tiempo, tenes que ejecutar esto a cada rato, y puede ser muy lento a la larga

Comment: @
FranklinMedina
 te pido que la proxima vez que hagas una pregunta, agregues todooooo lo que intentaste para no poner como respuesta algo que no sirve porque ya intentaste...

Comment: si el valor se modificara todos los días, es interesante por que prácticamente estaba haciendo algo parecido y el error que me daba era que no ponía el paréntesis y que la consulta, yo acabo de hacer la prueba y no me funciona  esta bien y hace el Update a acumulado pero me arroja un mismo valor en los dos códigos, yo lo estaba haciendo así, UPDATE codigo SET acumulado = ( SELECT sum(valores) as puntos from codigos c INNER JOIN código ON codigo = c.codigos GROUP BY codigo) , pero de esta forma tampoco funciona aunque el select si esta bien hecho

Comment: disculpa si se enviaron muchas respuestas la costumbre de dar espacio y se enviaba la respuesta incompleta

Comment: probaste lo que puse como respuesta? @FranklinMedina y repito, la proxima vez, en tu pregunta, agrega todo lo que intentaste...

Comment: si ya funciona perfecto gracias, sobre lo otro no lo había intentado en el momento de generar la pregunta fue después de generarla, igualmente la siguiente vez será de esa forma de verdad muchas gracias

Comment: Lo otro no te funciona porque el inner join junta todas las filas de las dos tablas, y entonces en el sub select esta devolviendo un conjunto de datos y no uno solo como te mostre en la respuesta... @FranklinMedina